# fullcalendar events displayed twice

Tags: bootstrap-4, fullcalendar

I've searched on stackoverflow for an answer, but not found anything.

I have used full-calendar to create a dynamic calendar on 2 charity sites I run - the calendar displays on one, but not properly on the other and I can't see any differences that might cause the issue.

Working as expected:

[Paphos](https://www.rotary-site.org/paphos-aphrodite/cal.html)

Events displaying twice:

[District](https://www.rotary-ribi.org/districts/calendar4.php?DistrictNo=1180)

Hope it's something blindingly obvious that I've missed!

Thanks

Chris

Comment: without seeing how you generate your events or set up yoour calendar,it's hard to be sure. The source code of the second page looks ok by itself. Demo using your code: http://jsfiddle.net/9a86h74m/14/

Comment: you do have a syntax error on that page from some other code, so fix that and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson - I'm not a tecchie, so could you point out what the syntax error is and what it should be?

Comment: @ADyson; fixed them, but no difference.